# Run powershell without 'run script'

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell file (folderWatcher.ps1), which I run using powershell ISE.

I have placed 'folderWatcher.ps1' in my startup folder, so the file opens up when the machine is switched on.

However, the script does not run unless I select the "Run Script" button (or F5) once.

(After that the script runs perfectly till the machine is shut down.)

Now, my query is:  How do I run the script without selecting "Run script" button ?  -- All my tasks in this process are automated, except the "Run script".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing the PS1 file in your start-up folder place a shortcut there.
I have tested the following successfully:

In the folder

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

I created a windows shortcut with this text in the target:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file C:\Scripts\FolderWatcher.ps1
```

This script ran without prompting at log on.

Comment: thanks for your reply. This is not working. any suggestions pls

Comment: I have updated my answer with the exact shortcut I tested successfully.